# Commercial use of droidtext for Android to generate PDF document from my App

Tags: android, pdf, android-droidtext

I have an Android app that currently generates a HTML file as the output when information is exported. I want to give users the option of exporting to a PDF document as well. I reached out to the good folks at iText but they want more than I can afford.

I read about the droidtext project and the fact that it can be used for commercial applications, provided one follows certain requirements. Can someone explain what I should do to be able to use droidtext in my app so I may sell on Google Play?

Comment: It tooks 10 seconds with Google to find out it's licensed under LGPL.  Now what's the question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and time. I was looking for instructions or steps for the licence compliance. It appears that they were already available in the droidText project site that I didnt notice earlier.. Please see below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed steps for LGPL compliance are already available on the droidtext project site.. Missed seeing it earlier.. Here is the link...

http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/wiki/LGPLCompliance

Comment: The link gives a "404. That’s an error."

Comment: Yeah. That project has been taken off.